# Cant connect Phoenix to Hbase using sqlline

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix, sqlline

I am using Hbase 1.2.6, phoenix-4.13.1-HBase-1.2, hadoop 2.9.0, in pseudo distributed setup. I can create tables in hbase shell, and I want to use phoenix to read those tables. I get the following error when running 'sqlline.py localhost:2181:/hbase-unsecure' :

```
Setting property: [incremental, false]
Setting property: [isolation, TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED]
issuing: !connect jdbc:phoenix:localhost:2181:/hbase-unsecure none none org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver
Connecting to jdbc:phoenix:localhost:2181:/hbase-unsecure
18/02/05 14:30:26 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Error: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Can't get the locations (state=,code=0)
java.sql.SQLException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Can't get the locations
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$12.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2492)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$12.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2384)
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.PhoenixContextExecutor.call(PhoenixContextExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.init(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2384)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.getConnectionQueryServices(PhoenixDriver.java:255)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.createConnection(PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.java:150)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.connect(PhoenixDriver.java:221)
    at sqlline.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:157)
    at sqlline.DatabaseConnection.getConnection(DatabaseConnection.java:203)
    at sqlline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:1064)
    at sqlline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:996)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sqlline.ReflectiveCommandHandler.execute(ReflectiveCommandHandler.java:38)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:809)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.initArgs(SqlLine.java:588)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:661)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:398)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:291)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Can't get the locations
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.getRegionLocations(RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.java:319)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:156)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:210)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.call(ClientScanner.java:327)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.nextScanner(ClientScanner.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.initializeScannerInConstruction(ClientScanner.java:167)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.<init>(ClientScanner.java:162)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getScanner(HTable.java:797)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.fullScan(MetaTableAccessor.java:602)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.tableExists(MetaTableAccessor.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.tableExists(HBaseAdmin.java:406)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$12.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2412)
    ... 20 more
sqlline version 1.2.0
0: jdbc:phoenix:localhost:2181:/hbase-unsecur>
```

hbase-site.xml file:

```
<configuration>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/Users/nishanksogani/HbaseInstall/zookeeper</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
    <value>/hbase</value>
  </property>

    <property>
      <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>


</configuration>
```

Any help will be appreciated!

**Update:**
I checked my zookeeper files, cleaned all exsting files and restarted the zookeeper and Hbase. The reqd files were created and I was able to connect phoenix to hbase using './sqlline.py localhost'

Answer (score 0):

The issue is very clear.
Your hbase zookeeper znode is /hbase, while you try to connect phoenix by /hbase-unsecure.

I'm facing same issue in the other way. 
In HDP2.6 without kerberos, the znode for hbase is /hbase-unsecure.
So I got same error while connect jdbc:phoenix:myhost, which using default znode(/hbase)

Hope my post will save half an hour for someone like me.

PS: the port in jdbc string is for zookeeper. So don't try to use 8765(phoenix port) as stupid as I do.